# how to check if user input already exists in a text file python

Tags: python

How can I check if the input already exists in the text file?

```
def Database():

    file=open("Database.txt","a")

    print("Welcome to Database")
    name=input("Enter your name\n")
    username=input("Enter your username\n")
    password=input("Enter your password\n")
    date=input("Enter the date\n")

    while True:
        if username in file():
            print("Already exists")
            username=input("Enter your username\n")
        else:
            file.write(name)
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(username)
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(password)
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(date)
            file.write("\n")

    file.close()

Database()
```

Comment: First off, `file` isn't callable; you can `read` from it, though.

Comment: You can't read from `file` if it was opened `"a"`.

Comment: Hopefully in a real application you would not be storing passwords in plain text....

Comment: what does that even mean, i am a beginner

Comment: What should i do then?

Comment: Open the file with read mode, take the data from it in the way you need it and store it in a list.Then close the file completely.Now ask for user to enter the text then check if this text exists in the list you previously saved,if it exists do what is required, if not then append it to the file using file_mode='a'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to search the file several times, until the customer enters a new username, I recommend that you break this into steps:

1. Read the file into a data structure you find convenient, some sort of table of usernames.  Close the file.
2. When the customer enters a name, you use the **in** operator to check the list of existing names.
3. Once you get the new information, open the file again for "append", and add the new information to the file.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: If it's duplicate data, then step 3 doesn't apply: "Once you get *new* information ..."

Answer (score 1):

1. Read the file from start to end and save it in a list.
2. Since you are going to check several times, it is better to save the entire list in a csv file in a single line.
   This will reduce the read time.
3. Then simply check if username in csv file or not.

Add the following snippet and change according to the requirement.

```
import csv
alreadyIn=[]

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        alreadyIn.append(row[0])

with open('data.csv', 'w+') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow([alreadyIn])

with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        allData = row[0]
if newInput in allData:
    #your operations
```